# Proof Verification: No $x$ such that $e^x$ = 0

Tags: solution-verification

In my school's grade 10 curriculum we learnt something called the natural logarithm. And of course, comes $ln(0) = undefined$.

Now of course, every generic math teacher should ask their students, "Why?"

Here's my try:
$$e^{a + bi} = e^a \times e^{bi} = 0$$and since $e^a > 0$,
$$e^{bi} = 0$$ which implies that $$e^{(\pi\times\frac{b}{\pi}\times i)}=0$$
Let $c = \frac{b}{\pi}$, then $$(e^{\pi i})^{c} = \cos(\pi c) + i  \sin (\pi c) = 0. $$

thus $$\cos(\pi c) = -i \sin (\pi c)$$
and since $\cos(x), \sin(x)$ for all real $x$ is real, $$\cos (\pi c) =-i \sin(\pi c)=0$$which has no solutions.

My questions:

1. Is this proof valid?
2. Are there faster way to make this proof?
3. Are there any "newbies-will-understand-this" proof? (a.k.a. not using Euler's number, trigonometry, and such))

Comment: You can write $e^{bi}=\cos b+i\sin b$ without factoring $\pi$ out (which is a pointless thing to do).

Comment: I would write $e^x \cdot e^{-x} = 1$, hence both are non zero.

Comment: @copper.hat I didn't think of that solution actually. An interesting one.

Comment: @runway44 Thanks for the info. I used the trick I learnt in school and didn't realize I can factor the $\pi$ out.

Comment: I think that is how Rudin does it.

Comment: @copper.hat How'd you write that "dot" in the MathJax?

Comment: @MarioPrix Hover over the expression, right click and select Show Math As -> TeX Commands to see the code, In this case it is backslash cdot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The proof itself is correct, except that you didn't justify that $e^a > 0$. I think this is an important point. Those 10th graders probably aren't learning about the complex exponential, and certainly not the complex logarithm. Your proof shows that the complex exponential never reaches $0$ given that the real exponential never reaches $0$, but it seems to me that the latter is what you're really interested in. The solution @copper.hat gave in the comments shows this. It's also worth thinking about why $e^a$ is positive, as you claim in your proof.
2. The argument in the comments is very fast. If you want to make the argument you gave more concise, you can note that $|e^{ib}| = 1$. Indeed, $e^{ib} = \cos(b) + i \sin(b)$ so $|e^{ib}| = \sqrt{\cos(b)^2 + \sin(b)^2} = 1$ by the Pythagorean theorem. Hence, $|e^{a + bi}| = e^a$ which is nonzero.
3. As I remarked in (1.), I don't think a newbie who is unfamiliar with trigonometry should be learning about the complex exponential at all! The actual question is about the real exponential, and the proof in the comments works well there too. Also, I certainly don't know a way to explain that $e^x$ is nonzero without using Euler's number, since that's just $e^1$.

Comment: Nice answer. For (3), I meant that the proof should not use any identity like $e^{ib} = \cos (b) + i \sin (b)$ for the "not using Euler's number" part.